# Thinking_Sphinx working in console but not in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Environment Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.8.7, Sphinx 0.99, Dreamhost VPS

I have a simple blog search set up as follows:

Controller:

```
def blog_search_results     
    @blog_search_results = BlogPost.search( params[:search_param] )
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { render :partial => 'blog_search_results', :layout=>false }
      format.xml  { render :xml     => @blog_search_results }
    end     
end
```

View:

```
<% if !@blog_search_results.empty? %>
    <div id="main_content">
        <table id="pending_blog_list"><tr id="header"><td>Blog Title</td><td>Created by</td><td>Created on</td></tr>
        <% @blog_search_results.each do |blog_post| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= link_to blog_post.title, blog_named_link(blog_post, :show) %></td>
                <td><%= blog_post.posted_by.display_name -%></td>
                <td><%= blog_post.created_at.strftime("%x") -%></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
        <%= will_paginate(@blog_search_results, {:form_name => :blog_show_params, :param_name => :page} ) %>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <h2>No blog posts that match your search were found</h2>
<% end %>
```

Everything works perfectly in my development environment. In the production environment, when I launch a console ("rails c production") and type:

> irb(main):003:0>
>   BlogPost.search("video")

I get the expected 4 results of posts with the word 'video'. However in the actual app, the controller keeps returning a '404 Not Found'

```
Started GET "/blog_posts/blog_search_results?search_param=video" 
Processing by BlogPostsController#blog_search_resul as HTML   
Parameters: {"search_param"=>"video"} 
Completed in 27ms 
Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (22.3ms)
Rendered public/404.html within layouts/blog_posts (24.7ms)
```

My sphinx.yml setup is as follows:

```
staging:
  pid_file: '/www.assetcorr.com/current/log/searchd.pid'
  searchd_file_path: 'www.assetcorr.com/shared/db/sphinx'
  bin_path: '/home/avitus/local/bin'
```

I see the index in the in the shared/db/sphinx folder. It appears after I run ts:index.
The searchd.pid file is in the log folder and the PID matches the searchd daemon.
The bin_path is correct and I've added it to the path in the .bash_profile file.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

-- UPDATE --

It look as though the reason this isn't working is that the controller method is being accessed via an AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_param").observe_field(0.5, function( ) { 
    $.get("/blog_posts/blog_search_results", { search_param: this.value },
      function(data){   
    $("#search_results").html(data);
      }, "html");
    });
  });
});
```

When I remove the AJAX call and resort to a plain vanilla GET request then it works perfectly. I have no idea why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the path of the Thinking Sphinx. I hope you are running on Passenger. please specify the path in sphinx.yml(what ever is your sphinx config yml file)

Comment: I am running on Passenger. I've pasted the sphinx.yml settings above

Comment: You need to restart the passenger after setting the bin path.